# prev_execution_date in Airflow

Tags: airflow

In [Airflow macros](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/macros-ref) we can find `prev_execution_date`, that, according to the docs, it returns

> the previous execution date (if available)

What happens in the first execution? Does it return an empty string? Does it return a `None`? Is this documented somewhere?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it is the first execution, `prev_execution_date` will return the (`execution_date` - `scheduler_interval`) of the DAG for a Scheduled Dag.

If the Dag is manually triggered, it returns the `execution_date`.

Comment: https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/59dad1a4ea6f3ba39d7be8c46ee45ea7cb0dd1f9/airflow/models/taskinstance.py#L1442-L1465